# Urbanairship: Delay in delivery of first push notification.

Tags: ios, objective-c, push, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I have heard that when using urbanairship, there is a delay of almost 24 hours in delivery of first push notification to a device. Is this correct? I have added an app and sent a push notification but though there is no error on erro console but I have not got the push on my device yet after 10 minutes of sending it. Can any one please guide me?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a 24 hour delay on push delivery using Urban Airship. There are many reasons a push may not be successful. I recommend you email Urban Airship Support at support@urbanairship.com so we can look into your particular situation. You can also check out our troubleshooting guide at https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client%3A+iOS%3A+Push#ClientiOSPush-Troubleshooting

Thank you,

Urban Airship Support

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Ruth White mentioned, the delay you might perceive while using push notification for apple services is that development servers are not as fast as production servers. If you are using development servers, sometimes, for some circumstances, it can take several minutes before receiving a push notification. This is not controlled by Urban Airship, it's apple development servers.